# Setting a range for Random float generation in Ada

Tags: random, range, ada

Adam.Numerics.Float_Random generates Float values for `0 - 1.0` but i want to generate a Float value between a user defined range. Like `Min := 100.0` and `Max := 200.0`. Something like this:

```
with Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Float_Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO, Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Float_Random; use Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;

procedure test1 is
  
   Min, Max, Answer : Float;
   
   subtype Custom is Float range Min .. Max;
   package New_Package is new Ada.Numerics.Float_Random(Custom);
   use New_Package;
   
   RF : Generator;
   
begin

Reset(RF);

Get(Min);
Get(Max);
Answer := Random(RF);
Put(Answer, Fore => 1, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);

end test1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like homework... I usually don't give the answer for such a task :)

First of all, you should get a warning when compiling your code as *Min* and *Max* are uninitialized when building your subtype.

To avoid this, the subtype must be declared after values are known.
To do this, declare your subtype inside a declare block.

About the random generation, getting a value inside your range is only a matter of translating and scaling.

In the end, I would do something like this.

```pascal
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Float_Random; use Ada.Numerics.Float_Random;

procedure test1 is
   
   Min, Max : Float;
   
   RF : Generator;
   
begin
   
   Reset(RF);
   
   Get(Min);
   Get(Max);
   declare
      subtype Custom is Float range Min .. Max;
      Answer : Custom;
   begin
      Answer := (Random(RF) * (Max - Min)) + Min;
      Put(Answer, Fore => 1, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
   end;
end test1;
```

In this particular case, the subtype is quite useless here.